# Resharper 8 not inspecting certain files in VS 2013

Tags: resharper

For example, I have an app.js file which resharper ignores.  As soon as I rename this file to app1.js, resharper starts inspecting it.  Once I rename it back to app.js resharper ignores it once again.

Note: I do not think this issue is specific to RS 8 or VS 2013

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the file comes from a nuget package. ReSharper doesn't analyse files that come from nugets, because you typically don't edit them, and they'll be updated when you next update the package. It's not your code, and you shouldn't be nagged to try and fix it.

Comment: That seems like a possibility.  Although I have not seen this before when working with Nuget code.  Any idea on how to make RS inspect all files?